# add json data to middleware request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to express and node, I working on a task where I want to add some json data to middleware request, here is the approach I am following:

In my middleware I want to add some details to request like current date and time and then extract the URL path. Here is the code I came up with:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
module.exports = app.use('/some-url', function(req, res, next) {
     let logdetails = {
      id: "some-id",
      datetime: Date.now(),
      path: '/path-in-url'
    }
    req.logdetails= logdetails;
    next();
} );
```

I am using `module.exports` so it this function is exported. But it is giving errors. Also what is the correct way to access the URL path, for example if URL is `/users/john` then I want to extract `/john` and my middleware should be applied only when URL starts with `/users`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the middleware then just export the middleware function. Not the Whole `app.use` part. I think `app.use` returns an Express object. And `:param` in your url will make sure that you can access that parameter. You can check out more about path patterns [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use)

**middleware.js**

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
     let logdetails = {
      id: "some-id",
      datetime: Date.now(),
      path: '/path-in-url'
    }
    req.logdetails= logdetails;
    next();
}
```

**Your other main.js file:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const middleWare = require('./middleware')

app.use('/users/:name', middleWare, (req, res)=>{
  //you can access logDetails
  // and the name
  const name = req.params.name;//This will be john for /users/john
  const logDetails = req.logdetails;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

> Also what is the correct way to access the URL path, for example if
>   URL is /users/john then I want to extract /john

If your request url is `/users/john` then `req.path` will give you the path of the request url, i.e. `/users/john`. To extract john, you can use [named route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) and define your route as `/users/:name`. After using named route parameter in your route, if your request url is `/users/john`, `req.params.name` will give you the route parameter, i.e. john. For more details, take a look at [req.params on express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params)

> and my middleware should be applied only when URL starts with /users

following middleware will only run when request path is `/users`

```
app.use('/users', (req, res, next) => {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

req.originalUrl returns the url path like shown below

```
// GET /search?q=something
console.dir(req.originalUrl)
// => '/search?q=something'
```

source: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Similarly, get the URL path and split the string accordingly and apply the condition you need.

Here if your originalPath is /users/john then

```
const result = "/users/john".split("/")
```

would result in `["", "users", "john"]`

Check if the `result[1]==="users"` and write your condition in the middleware.

You don't have to export the middle ware.

Answer (score 1):

### middleware.js

```
module.exports = {
    handler: (req, res, next) => {
        const userName = req.params.name;

        // add payload to request

        next();
    }
}
```

### app.js

```
middleware = require("middleware");

app.use('/users/:name', middleware.handler);
```

Concerning URL path access you could get access using `request params`, e.g

```
app.use('/users/:name', (req, res, next) => {
    const userName = req.params.name;

    // add payload to request

    next();
});

 1. Register your specific URL - `/users/:name`, where `:name` is dynamic params e.g *john*
 2. Grab params in the callback
```